# NSIS - Close current window

Tags: nsis

I am creating an installer using NSIS. When the user clicks on the executable once again, I am proceeding with the installation again and getting a description from the user. This leads to installing multiple instances of the same application.

On this page, I am showing a cancel button to exit the setup, but I am not able to close the current installer application. If the user clicks the cancel button to abort the application, I want to close the setup.

What can I do to make the cancel button cancel the current install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only imagine a reason why your Cancel button isn't working... Maybe you have defined a bogus `.onUserAbort` callback function? If you do an `Abort` inside .onUserAbort, you are preventing the user closes the installer...